# sql date difference with multiple variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get the number of days difference in dates between the effdate status 0 that follows the **most recent** status 1

the code below yields the following results

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT FILEKEY, STATUS, EFFDATE  FROM ASTATUSHIST
UNION
SELECT FILEKEY, ASTATUS, ASTATUSEFFDATE FROM USERS ) A

ORDER BY 1, 3 DESC

130 0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000
130 0   2017-03-01 00:00:00.000
130 0   2017-01-01 00:00:00.000
130 1   2005-02-01 00:00:00.000
130 0   2001-03-03 00:00:00.000
130 0   2000-01-30 00:00:00.000
130 0   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

this code combines 2 tables to get the complete history for a given user.
Ideally I could produce something that looks like this:

```
130    4352
```

or

```
125    null
```

where the null is filekey without a status 1 or a filekey with a status 1 but without a following status 0

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: I'm a lowly tech.  This isn't exactly my option.

Answer (score 0):

In all supported versions of SQL Server, you can use window functions:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*,
       datediff(day, date, next_date) as days_diff
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by filekey, status order by date desc) as seqnum,
             lead(date) over (partition by filekey order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```